# Separate registration form for professional customer prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I want to create a separate form for professional customer with few special rules. The new registration form will have company name instead of firstname and lastname. Is there a way to create separate registration form in prestashop?

My prestashop version is 1.6.1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the B2B mode in PrestaShop, this will be handled for you.

In Preferences > Customer:
[image]